# Css issue in firefox on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

The problem is is not showing correctly on firefox mobile devices tested on phone and tablet. Desktop version of firefox or chrome is working fine but not on mobile firefox. Google chrome mobile is working fine as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<input id="copyprice" type="text" class="form-control input-lg custom" size="3" value="8,425" />
<select onchange="doReload(this.value);" class="form-control input-lg custom">
<option value="aud">USD</option>
<option selected="selected" value="usd">USD</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>

.custom
{
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
}

input, select
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
```

See red line, there are 1 or 2px differences which I can't fix them no matter what I tried. The problem is the second box which is higher not the first one if that helps.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/xt45drw6/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that css:

```
.custom {
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: This works as well and I think this is the right answer for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add `vertical-align: top`

```
.custom
{
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This works despite the fact is not arranged anymore with some text which I have in the left side but I have to modify there as well.